# How can I call an object property with a variable?

Tags: javascript, string, object, dynamic

I am trying to solve an issue of calling an object property + function with string.

For example:

```
var myobject = {
   firstName: "Bob",
   lastName: "Joe"
};
var show = "lastName";
myobject[show].thisfunction();
```

In the console everything works as I would expect, but in code it says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The first example isn't valid JS as Bob and Joe aren't shown to be strings, and you can't pass a type definition to an [] operator

Comment: "but in code it says" -- who says it? :) Show the exact line.

Comment: Where did you define thisfunction?

Comment: Actually I found the problem, it was dumb...in my code one line somewhere else had myobject.[show].thisfunction();

Answer (score 2):

This is how it will be done
Here if How you can call the Function on it.

if you want to call the function from current class instance then just replace `obj` with `this`.

```js
var proprt = 'firstName'
var myobject = {
   firstName: "Bob",
   lastName: "Joe"
};


var a  =() => { alert('Hello') }

var obj = { Bob:{ thisFn: a } }

obj[myobject[proprt]].thisFn()
```

Comment: I updated the first example a bit to be clearer, I would like to be able to call properties dynamically where "show" is a variable that can change between property names for the object.

Comment: This is the correct answer if the property is passed as a variable

Comment: Editing the Snippet to be Clear